# Add Needs to View Recipient to Template

Tags: c#, sdk, docusignapi

I need to add a user/role/template role that only requires "Needs To View".  I tried creating a template role with no tabs that would make it "Needs to View" however that did not work.  Below is what I have tried:

```
 var acadRecRole = new TemplateRole
            {
                // todo: replace value
                //Email = "academic.records@sru.edu",
                Email = "crmckain@gmail.com",
                RoleName = "AcadRecViewer",
                Name = "Academic Records",
                RoutingOrder = "2"
            };

envelope.TemplateRoles.Add(acadRecRole);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different things to do:

1. Create a template and make sure it has a "Need To View" recipient
2. Create an envelope from this template and put the information for this recipient.

The code above is part of #2, although I don't see the part about setting a `templateId` which should be in your `EnvelopeDefinition` object.

So, if you are asking how to do #2, you first have to ensure you did #1. You can do #1 from the web app, or from the API. To do it from the web app just go to your template and when adding a new recipient pick the "Need To View" type and leave the email/name empty just put a placeholder/role name that you need to match above "AcadRecViewer".

Hope this makes sense. If you are trying to do #1 programmatically, it's also doable, but different code, similar to other code creating an envelope.

Comment: So I tried what you suggested about creating a role that "Needs to View" and when I ran the app the role was converted somehow to "Needs to Sign".

Comment: So I did what you suggested but I had to insert a Name/Email onto the DocuSign GUI and not include those fields on the role itself in the code.

Comment: You can do it either way, I don't know what was the issue when you had it as a placeholder (role) but it will work as well.